# How can I segment a point cloud using normals?

Tags: c++, computer-vision, ros, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I am trying to segment a cylinder from a plane using conditional Euclidean Clustering (based on [this documentation](https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/latest/conditional_euclidean_clustering.html)). To test this out I have generated a point cloud consisting of just a plane and a cylinder, shown below:

[image: Original point cloud]

I have set up my custom Euclidean clustering as follows:

```
bool
enforceCurvatureSimilarity(const PointFull& point_a, const PointFull& point_b, float squared_distance)
{
  Eigen::Map<const Eigen::Vector3f> point_a_normal = point_a.getNormalVector3fMap (), point_b_normal = point_b.getNormalVector3fMap ();
  if (std::abs (point_a_normal.dot (point_b_normal)) > 0.7)
  {
    return (true);
  }
  return (false);
}
```

I calculate the normals and perform the clustering as follows:

```
    // Set up a Normal Estimation class and merge data in cloud_with_normals
    
    ne.setSearchMethod (search_tree);
    // setKSearch seems faster than radius search -> is it less accurate?
    ne.setKSearch (5);
    //ne.setRadiusSearch (0.1);
    // pcl::IntegralImageNormalEstimation<PointT, PointN> ne;
    // ne.setMaxDepthChangeFactor(0.02f);
    // ne.setNormalSmoothingSize(10.0f);
    ne.setInputCloud (cloud);
    ne.compute (*cloud_normals);

    pcl::concatenateFields (*cloud, *cloud_normals, *cloud_with_normals);

    // Set up a Conditional Euclidean Clustering class
    pcl::ConditionalEuclideanClustering<PointFull> cec (true);
    cec.setInputCloud (cloud_with_normals);
    cec.setConditionFunction (&enforceCurvatureSimilarity);
    //cec.setClusterTolerance (500.0);
    cec.setClusterTolerance(0.05);
    //Clusters that make up less than 0.1% of total cloud size considered too small
    cec.setMinClusterSize (cloud_with_normals->size () / 1000);
    //Clusters that make up more than 10% of total cloud size considered too large
    cec.setMaxClusterSize (cloud_with_normals->size () *0.1);
    cec.segment (*clusters);
    cec.getRemovedClusters (small_clusters, large_clusters);
```

However, when I try and segment the point cloud, everything is seen as a single cluster. I can think of two reasons as to why this might be happening.

The first being incorrect tuning of the parameters. I have tried many different combinations for both the normal estimation and clustering parameters, but have yet to see any real difference. At best a few points in the cylinder will be considered a separate cluster of one point.

The second reason is that the normals around the base of the cylinder are being incorrectly estimated due to the hard edge. This could be leading them to have an angle when they shouldn't which is breaking down the clustering algorithm. An example of this can be seen below:

[image: Normals with an incorrect angle.]

How can I fix this so that the segmentation works correctly?

Comment: Have you considered using RANSAC instead? Using RANSAC, it should be easy to get all points on the plane or all points on the cylinder.

Comment: @IBitMyBytes I have used RANSAC, but I would like to use this method of segmentation as an initial step for other environments where RANSAC would not be as directly applicable. In fact, I would like to use this to segment off different objects in the environment and then apply RANSAC primitive fitting to just these objects.

Answer (score 0):

May be useing [DoN](https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/master/don_segmentation.html#don-segmentation) is better for this situation. Your point cloud is sparse,even the normal estimate being incorrectly on the plane.

Comment: If you find the reason that occur the error, please share it!  There is a good chance to study PCL for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @zxh251 I tried DoN-based segmentation, but also could not quite get it to work. This could be because I was using incorrect parameters. Since in the final point clouds I will be using I also have RGB data, I have opted for a colour-based segmentation method.

Comment: I'm doing some work similar to you. I try to detect some circular blind via from a plane using region growing segmention. I'll let you know if I get a good outcome.